# Updating location via data stream using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, openlayers

I'm developing a application where I need to real-time update a location of a map using a data stream. I'm planning to use web-sockets and Leaflet.

Are there any guides I can follow or can you direct me in the correct path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a post I have written regarding how to achieve this, I have covered many things including web-sockets here.

http://yasassriratnayake.blogspot.com/2014/09/developping-web-bases-realtime-updating.html

Comment: It would be useful if you put the essential parts of the answer in the body itself, to avoid Link rot

Answer (score 1):

The live data stream at my end was coming as json by a GET api call to backend. In your case with sockets also you're going to get the latest data in a new socket message in json probably; once you have the payload these next steps should be the same. I wrote the updating logic myself, and for visual animation aspect I used this slideto plugin listed in the offical leafletjs plugins page: https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Marker.SlideTo

To start with, I kept a top-level json variable that holds the markers, in addition to the leaflet layer.

```
var mapLayer = new L.featureGroup();
// using featureGroup instead of layerGroup so that we can used getBounds() to zoom to all items in the layer
var collection = {};
```

On first load, this creator function loops through each item in the live data feed, creates a marker for it, and additionally makes the marker a member of the collection json.

```
function createItem(item) {
    let id = item['id'];
    collection[id] = L.marker([item["latitude"], item["longitude"]], {
        // customising the marker based on values of item
    });
    mapLayer.addLayer(collection[id]);
}
```

Then on subsequent updates, a sliding function is called:

```
function slideitem(item) {
    let id = item['id'];
    collection[id].slideTo([item["latitude"], item["longitude"]], {
        duration: 300,
        keepAtCenter: false,
    });
}
```

By using the collection json, I'm able to directly access the marker object and make changes to it, rather than having to bother going into the layer and searching for it, or recreating the whole layer etc.

There's a lot of other things one can build around this like updating the content of the popup / tooltip if open while moving, changes to the marker size, opacity, deciding not to slide if the change in co-ordinates isn't too much, etc. For having this flexibility I decided to code the live updating part myself rather than rely on another lib.

Answer (score 0):

Late response, but here is a talk demoing how to use vert-x, Leaflet and websockets for a real-time bus position tracker
http://vimeo.com/106234599

Answer (score -1):

[leaflet-geojson-stream](https://github.com/tmcw/leaflet-geojson-stream/blob/master/example/server.js)

This will be the answer.