# Can we use PostGIS functions in Openlayers?

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2

i have a traffic data (vehicles gps location(Point)) for every minute in a specific location

*sample data :* **Vehicle_No , Long, Lat**

and i need to show the real time traffic for that specific location in openlayers  which has to be updated every minute.

**one solution** is to import traffic data into PostGis and create a new cloumn which use ST_Buffer function to find out how many no. of vehicles are near by each other and can export the table to the openlayers and give them colour (red,orange,blue) according to no. of vehicles (the buffer column produced). 
- the problem with this approach is that we have to manually do the buffer operations and update the openlayers every minute.

Can someone suggest me some better approach to do this?

Comment: You may hide PostGIS behind a web map service (WMS or WFS), you have to refresh the map from Openlayers regularly, while data are updated in PostGIS independently.

Comment: See here for a PostGIS-based solution: http://blogs.intevation.de/slt/post/pointstream/

Comment: And here for some alternative ideas using Openlayers: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98130/how-to-update-location-via-a-data-stream-in-openlayers-or-leaflet

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, of course you can do this, here are the simple steps:

- Make a **[SQL View](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html)** in Geoserver for **St_Buffer** PostGIS function or **St_Within** function.
- Then, using openlayers call a WFS or WMS request to SQL View in Geoserver, and now you will have either GeoJSON or Raster(png, jpeg etc) output depends on request type.
- Now, you just need to make a layer and load the response data.